# Animating UIImageView with colorWithPatternImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` that is animated using the following code:

```
    NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"marker_%i.png", i];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:str];
        if(img != nil) {
            [imageArray addObject:img];
        }

    }

    _imageContainer.animationImages = imageArray;

    _imageContainer.animationDuration = 0.5f;
    [_imageContainer startAnimating];
```

What I want now is to repeat the image to get a pattern. There is `colorWithPatternImage`, but that isn't made for animations.

I want the whole background filled with a animated pattern.
Instead of using a very large images (960x640) i could use a image of 64x64 for example and repeat that to fill the screen.

Is there any way?

Comment: What exactly do you mean repeat to get a pattern? You want your background to be animated? Or you want to record the animation and repeat it? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i edited my first post to provide more detail.

Comment: So you want the standard functionality of `colorWithPatternImage:` but animated? Thats a tough one. Hmmm.

Comment: I suppose you could repeat the view and push it on as many times as you needing, adjusting its position with each pass. The problem of course, is the timing would never be perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave your code as it is, but instead using `UIImageView` use my subclass:

```
//
//  AnimatedPatternView.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AnimatedPatternView : UIImageView;    
@end
```

---

```
//
//  AnimatedPatternView.m
//

#import "AnimatedPatternView.h"

@implementation AnimatedPatternView

-(void)setAnimationImages:(NSArray *)imageArray
{
    NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:imageArray.count];

    for (UIImage* image in imageArray) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, YES, 0);
        UIColor* patternColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
        [patternColor setFill];
        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextFillRect(ctx, self.bounds);
        UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        [array addObject:img];

    }
    [super setAnimationImages:array];
}

@end
```

If you create the view using interface builder you only need to set the class of the image view in the identity inspector.

Comment: NICE!!! works really easy. Transparency of a png image is lost, that gets black now, any way to fix this? (not really important but I might need it later).

Comment: @clankill3r just change the 2nd argument of UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to NO