# How to make UIView not appear on background but still appear over a UIImageView (subview)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have a UIImageView. I also have a view. I want the view to appear on top of the UIImageView as it animates across the screen. I DO NOT want the view to appear in the background though.

How can I do this?

I have tried changing the order of subviews by adding another subview however this is impossible to do.

I was considering using a layer rather than a view to animate however the UIImageView has transparent portions around it.

Code: (note: isAnimating is a class property, don't worry about it)

```
@IBAction func AnimateBtnTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (isAnimating == false) {

        isAnimating = true

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, delay: 0.0, options: .Repeat, animations: {
            self.glintImageConstraint.constant += 450
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)


    } else {

        isAnimating = false

        self.glintImageView.layer.removeAllAnimations() //stop animation
        self.glintImageConstraint.constant = -200 //set glintImage to original position
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }
}
```

My UIImageView is a medallion. The glintImageView is the object animation across on top of it.

EDIT: I am asking for an equivalent to Shimmer ( https://github.com/facebook/Shimmer ) however for UIImageView.

Comment: Add your code. What have you done?

Comment: Sorry. Added it. ImageView and view are each added via storyboard/autolayout.

Comment: I am attempting to emulate the effect shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_U23xAUY6N4

Comment: If you are just needing to bring the subview to the front you can just use bringSubviewToFront.

Comment: No..that is DEFINITELY NOT what I am looking to do..

Comment: This is what i am doing however with a set of images instead of a uilabel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336505/ios-7-1-slide-to-unlock-text-animation

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use Core Animation. If you used a `CALayer` for the image view and added a mask layer to it, then used a sublayer for the view you want to appear on top of the image, it might work.